# Problems to get a solution in geometry

Tags: warning-messages, geometry

I set out to study about vectors and I think I am mistaking me something.

I created the following situation:

[image]

I am basing me about this concept:

[image]

This is my code:

```
u={3,1,1}
v={-4,1,3}
w={1,2,0};
o = {0, 0, 0};
Graphics3D[{Text[Style["\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(u\), \(\[RightVector]\)]\)", Large, Bold, Red], {(u - o)/2}],Text[Style["\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(v\), \(\[RightVector]\)]\)", Large, Bold, Red], {(v - o)/2}],Text[Style["\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(w\), \(\[RightVector]\)]\)", Large, Bold, Red], {(w - o)/2}], Arrow[{o, u}], Arrow[{o, v}], Arrow[{o, w}], Green, PointSize[.03], Point[{0, 0, 0}], Blue, PointSize[.02], Point[u], Point[v], Point[w] }, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> Automatic]

x = {xi, xj, xk};
Solve[Dot[x, w]/(Norm[x]*Norm[w]) == 0 && Cross[x, u] == v && Sqrt[ xi^2 + xj^2 + xk^2] = 1, {xi, xj, xk}]
```

The result is telling me that there are several solutions or that there is no solution?

Until I tried to insert a unit vector, but I think not worked out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I run your code (after correcting the equation `Sqrt[ xi^2 + xj^2 + xk^2] = 1` to `Sqrt[ xi^2 + xj^2 + xk^2] == 1`—note the double equals sign) Mathematica returns the result

```
{}
```

which means that **there are no solutions to your equations.**

In fact, this is because your vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ are not perpendicular.  Since $\vec{x} \times \vec{u} = \vec{v}$, and the cross product of two vectors is always perpendicular to both of those vectors, there cannot be a solution to this equation.